# How to update the Options Object in the beforeSubmit function using jQuery Forms Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I am refactoring my use of `$.ajax` to submit forms using the jQuery Forms Plugin.  The [API](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) states that it is possible to pass any of the options passed to `$.ajax` to `$.ajaxSubmit`. I wish to modify the Options Object in the `beforeSubmit`, adding a `data` property.  Alerting the value of `options.beforeSubmit` in `processSubmit` suggests that this is the Options Object initialised by the handler and that the data is set, but as the Options Object has already been initialised with no `data` property, it isn't included in the post sent to the server. Is it possible to modify the Options Object in the `beforeSubmit`, or in some other way?

When the document is ready I bind a handler to `submit()`:

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
    var options = { dataType: 'json',
            beforeSubmit: processSubmit,
            success: endSubmit };
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

The `processSubmit(arr, $form, options)` function packages up data to be sent to the server as JSON:

```
function processSubmit(arr, $form, options) {
    var followers =[];
    $($("#follower-multi-select").children().filter("li")).each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        var fwr =  $(this).attr("id");
        followers.push(fwr);
      }
    });

    var postData = { followers : followers };
    alert('beforeSubmit is: ' + options.beforeSubmit);

    options.data = 'json='+$.toJSON(postData);
    alert('data set: ' + options.data);
}
```

The form HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="/myaction" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose your competitors</legend>
        <ul id="follower-multi-select" class="follower-multi-select">
            {% for f in follower_thumbs %}
            <li id="{{ f.hashedkey }}"><img src='{{ f.thumb }}' alt="{{ f.name }}" /><span class="name-multi-select">{{ f.name }}</span></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <input id="send" type="submit" class="large" value="send" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `beforeSubmit` you should use [the `beforeSerialize` option](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object), so your data gets included when it's serialized.  You're not setting `.data` on the options passed to `$.ajax()`, you're setting `.data` on the `$.ajaxSubmit()` options, which is a property on the plugin of extra data to include when it serializes.  When `beforeSubmit` happens, the serialization has *already* been completed, you need to step in before that, like this:

```
$("#myform").submit(function() {
    var options = { dataType: 'json',
            beforeSerialize: processSubmit,
            success: endSubmit };
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});

function processSubmit($form, options) {
    var followers = $("#follower-multi-select > li.selected").map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    var postData = { followers : followers };
    alert('beforeSubmit is: ' + options.beforeSubmit);

    options.data = 'json='+$.toJSON(postData);
    alert('data set: ' + options.data);
}
```

I also used [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and the [`>` child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) here to make the getting of your array much simpler, but your original method works...just note the important difference that the parameters are different on the callback from `beforeSubmit`, there's no `arr` parameter for the `beforeSerialize` callback.

Comment: thanks very much! Your use of map() is beautiful. The code now reads as you suggest. While the alert shows options.data as 'json={"followers": ["0c703d82ebfe2ebc34c7a0149708869e802f3428"]}', the console shows that the JSON passed to the server reads 'UnicodeMultiDict: UnicodeMultiDict([(u'0', u'j'), (u'1', u's'), (u'2', u'o'), (u'3', u'n'), (u'4', u'='), (u'5', u'{'), (u'6', u'"'), (u'7', u'f'), (u'8', u'o'), (u'9', u'l'), (u'10', u'l'), (u'11', u'o'), (u'12', u'w'), (u'13', u'e'), (u'14', u'r')...(u'63', u'}')])'. Am I missing something in how I am passing the JSON?